# Apache Camel: How do I use Aggregation to get the actual old exchange

Tags: java, apache-camel

Hy all,

I currently have the use case, where I need to call an endpoint in my route, but after that continue with the original Message.
The way I found to do it is using `multicast()` and then the AggregationStrategy `AggregationStrategies.useOriginal()`, i.e. `UseOriginalAggregationStrategy()`
To be clear, I'm not sending the message to multiple endpoint, just using the `multicast()` to "reset" the data to the state it was before

Now I had the issue where I had to propagate some information from inside the `multicast()` to the outside route and use it later (example below).
It tried to do this with an updated `UseOriginalAggregationStrategy()`, where I only "reset" the `Message`, but leave the `Exchange` as is, so I can update properties and still have them after the `multicast()`

AggregationStrategy:

```java
public class UseOriginalMessageAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {

  @Override
  public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
    if (oldExchange != null && oldExchange.getIn() != null) {
      newExchange.setIn(oldExchange.getIn());
    }
    return newExchange;
  }
}
```

UnitTest:

```java
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
  camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
      from("direct:test")
          .multicast(new UseOriginalMessageAggregationStrategy())
            .process(exchange -> { // This could also be a 'to()', it doesn't make a difference
              exchange.setProperty("c", 1);
              exchange.getIn().setHeader("d", 1);
            })
          .end()
          .log("Property a: ${exchangeProperty.a}")
          .log("Header b: ${header.b}")
          .log("Property c: ${exchangeProperty.c}")
          .log("Header d: ${header.d}");
    }
  });

  Exchange exchange = new ExchangeBuilder(camelContext)
      .withProperty("a", 1)
      .withHeader("b", 1)
      .build();
  camelContext.createProducerTemplate().send("direct:test", exchange);
}
```

Now what I would expect is this log:

> Property a: 1
>   Header b: 1
>   Property c: 1
>   Header d:

But what actually happens is:

> Property a: 1
>   Header b: 1
>   Property c: 1
>   Header d: 1

Note that "Header d" is still set, even though is belongs to the message inside the `multicast()`, which should have been overwitten by now.

After some debugging I noticed, that this happens because the 'oldExchange' in the AggregationStrategy is actually null at which point the log makes sense, because it is exactly the 'newExchange' that gets logged.

Now it gets very confusing to me.
Even though the 'oldExchange' is null, which means we do not have access to the Exchange that came before the `multicast()`, the `UseOriginalAggregationStrategy()` is still able to get exactly the exchange.

Here an example with the UnitTest from above:

```java
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
  camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

      from("direct:test")
          .multicast(AggregationStrategies.useOriginal()) // <- Using the camel AggregationStrategy now
            .process(exchange -> {
              exchange.setProperty("c", 1);
              exchange.getIn().setHeader("d", 1);
            })
          .end()
          .log("Property a: ${exchangeProperty.a}")
          .log("Header b: ${header.b}")
          .log("Property c: ${exchangeProperty.c}")
          .log("Header d: ${header.d}");
    }
  });

  Exchange exchange = new ExchangeBuilder(camelContext)
      .withProperty("a", 1)
      .withHeader("b", 1)
      .build();
  camelContext.createProducerTemplate().send("direct:test", exchange);
}
```

This logs (as you would expect):

> Property a: 1
>   Header b: 1
>   Property c:
>   Header d:

Apparently it does this by just returning null.
So when I return null in the AggregationStrategy I get the actual initial Exchange, but there is no way of having access to that Exchange directly in the AggregationStrategy?
This seems kind of weird to me, so I'm guessing there is something I'm missing.

Best regards
Chris

TL;DR:
How can I send an Exchange to another endpoint, and reset the message to what it was before while keeping the ExchangeProperties, that were set in that other endpoint

Answer (score 0):

Your goal here is to enrich your original payload with additional properties.
Enterprise Integration Patterns wise enricher pattern is better suited than multi cast.
https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/content-enricher.html and the ExampleAggregationStrategy class in that page.

```
public class ExampleAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {

    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange original, Exchange resource) {

        Object resourceResponse = resource.getIn().getBody();
        // retrieve stuff you want from resource exchange and add them as properties to to original
        return original;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well not really, as the route I send the data to can also modify some of the data of the original exchange/message, which I want to "reset" afterwards so they stay unchanged. The info I want to keep from the call are essentially "flags", that are set there

Comment: well. In the ExampleAggreagtionStratgey, 'original' exchange is the unmodified one. You get any thing you want from 'resource' exchange and set as properties or flags

Comment: Thats what I would expect, but thats not what happens. When only calling the AggregationStrategy once, the originalExchange is not the exchange from before the multicast, but it is null. Thus I do not have access to the exchange before the multicast

Comment: I am talking about 'original' exchange in ExampleAggregationStrategy class used in the enricher not the multicast you have. That class is here https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/content-enricher.html